# How to push numbers in Firebase from a variable without quotation marks?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to push the **Lat** and **Long** via a form into my Firebase Database from an **inputValue**

```
var latInput = document.querySelector('#lat');
var longInput = document.querySelector('#long');
var lat = latInput.value;
var long = longInput.value;
firebase.database().ref('business/' + document.querySelector('#uid').value).update({
          lat: lat,
          long: long,

      });
```

The problem is that when I do so, **quotation marks** are added to the numbers I push. How can I push **ONLY** numbers **without** the quotation marks ?

Comment: try using [parseFloat](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) to your `lat` and `long` variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `lat` and `long` retrieved from `input.value` are `string`. You can just use `parseFloat(lat)` and `parseFloat(long)` to convert them to `float` before pushing to firebase.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Works like a charm !